# How to get the last value selected from dropdown and disable it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two drop-down's, i want to disable the last value selected from the drop down and enable the previous value in other drop-down.

Let's say i have two drop-down's as below :

```
<select name="g1" id="box_g1">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<select name="g2" id="box_g2">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

If i select option : 'one' from box_g1 and then 'two' from box_g1 again (i.e. from the same box). then only the last value 'two' should be disabled in the next drop-down. Check the below fiddle :

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/mkma3803/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/mkma3803/29/**

Comment: Please check this fiddle too.. I want it in this code actually.http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/yww8apn9/

Comment: @adeneo Also the fiddle is not valid which you have provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try something like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var g1 = [],
        g2 = [];
    $('#box_g1 option').each(function(){g1.push($(this).val());});
    $('#box_g2 option').each(function(){g2.push($(this).val());});

    $('#box_g1').on('change', function(){
        var options = '',
            selected = $('#box_g1').val();
        for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i++){
            if(selected != g1[i] && selected != 'Select'){
                options += ('<option value="'+g2[i]+'">'+g2[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }
        $('#box_g2').empty().html(options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you please suggest me on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/yww8apn9/. By the time i will check with the script you have given.

Comment: I want to disable the value. but your query removes the values from the dropdown.

Comment: But u had given some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value of the last item selected from the first box, and then iterate through the 2nd box and compare the values to the stored value, disabling all those that match.

Comment: Can you please suggest me on this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/yww8apn9/